# Find the top of the tree(the root) in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a tree like this:

```
data Tree a
  = Empty
  | Leaf a
  | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) String
  deriving (Show)
```

and I need a function which finds the top of the tree. I have written this:

```
root :: Tree a -> a
root (Leaf a) = a
root (Node a _ _ _) = a
```

which perfectly works, but when I have an Empty tree, I have an error message.

If I add

```
root Empty = Empty
```

I have an error again because it does not return a value of type `a`. What can I do ?

Comment: You really should ask yourself first: How program should understand the root of empty tree. And tell us.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have no sensible value of `a` in case of the `Empty` constructor. The type `Maybe` encodes exactly what you need in this case: a sensible value or no value. Therefore the following would be an idiomatic way of implementing your function:

```
root :: Tree a -> Maybe a
root (Leaf a) = Just a
root (Node a _ _ _) = Just a
root _ = Nothing
```

You can easily compose this function with other functions of your library using [functors, applicative functors and monads](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html). E.g.:

```
functionOnPlainA :: a -> a
functionOnPlainA = error "implement me"

-- So simply we can lift our plain function to work on values of type `Maybe`.
-- This is a Functor example.
functionOnMaybeA :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
functionOnMaybeA = fmap functionOnPlainA

-- Because the above is so simple, it's conventional to inline it,
-- as in the following:
applyFunctionOnPlainAToResultOfRoot :: Tree a -> Maybe a
applyFunctionOnPlainAToResultOfRoot tree = fmap functionOnPlainA $ root tree

-- And here is an example of how Monads can serve us:
applyRootToMaybeTree :: Maybe (Tree a) -> Maybe a
applyRootToMaybeTree maybeTree = maybeTree >>= root
```

Comment: a try this,but now i have a lot of errors.
Every function in which i use the result from root sends me an error that "could'n match expected type a with actual type Maybe a".
My other functions are from the type  NameOfFunction :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a

Comment: @user3050163 You can easily compose those functions with this one, but you must [get yourself acquainted with Functors, Applicative Functors and Monads](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html). Well, the Functors at least.

Comment: I will really appreciate it if you told me directly what to do to compose the two functions.I read the book learn haskell for great good ,but i still dont understandt what i have to do now...

Comment: See the updates and make sure to check out [this tutorial](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html), because in my experience it is the best introduction to the subject.

Comment: Ok,in this function
alabala :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
alabala  (Node m l r " ") 
     | topR <= x = (Node x l r " ")
     | otherwise = Node topR l r " "
         where topR = root r
what i have to do to make it work??i want to work when the tree has top element(number),if it is nothing i dont want to continue.

Comment: You should ask a separate question concerning your `alabala` function and provide some context, because there are problems with the code you provided which are unrelated to the `root` function.